# FastText vectors for NER training using user_hooks

Tags: spacy, fasttext

I want to train NER with FastText vectors, I tried 2 approaches:

**1st Approach:**
Load blank 'en' model
Load fasttext vectors for 2M vocabulary using nlp.vocab.set_vector() function
Call begin_training() followed by the code that iterate over batches and call update function.

**2nd Approach:**
Load blank 'en' model
Add a custom component i.e 'FastTextModel' in pipeline which sets the user_token_hooks with key 'vector' as shown in following code
Call begin_training() followed by the code that iterate over batches and call update function.
LABEL = ['label_1', 'label_2']

def train_model(model):
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  # load existing spacy model

```
# Load Fasttext component
fasttext_component = FastTextModel(fasttext.load_model("cc.en.300.bin"))
nlp.add_pipe(fasttext_component, first=True) 

if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:           
    ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
    nlp.add_pipe(ner)
else:
    ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')

# Add new entity labels to entity recognizer
for i in LABEL:
    ner.add_label(i)   

optimizer = nlp.resume_training()

#Get names of other pipes to disable them during training to train only NER
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner' and pipe != 'FastTextModel']
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
    # Training code here
save_model(nlp, 'model_name', 'output_dir', 0)

class FastTextModel(object):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self._model = model

    def __call__(self, doc):
        doc.user_token_hooks["vector"] = self.vector
        return doc;

    def vector(self, obj1):
        return self._model.get_word_vector(obj1.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_model()
```

My questions are:

1. In first approach, is it correct way to load vectors using
   nlp.vocab.set_vector() function? All the vectors loaded by this
   function will be utilized by NER while training?
2. In second approach,
   will NER utilize 'vector' function of FastTextModel to get word
   vectors for feeding it to CNN while training? During training, will
   NER learn new representation of words? if so, If I load word vector
   using following code after training is finished, will model return
   new learned word representations or the once generated by
   FastTextModel's 'vector' function

   ````
   for d in doc:
       print(d.vector)```
   ````
3. If NER does not use user_token_hooks during training, then only way to use FastText embeddings it to load it as a static embedding table using npl.vocab.set_vector() function?
4. Is there is some way to log what vector are being fed to embed part of NER while training or testing?
5. What I understands by spaCy's documentation is while training model always learns new embedding but does it learn embedding for OOV words as well? and how to know for which OOV words model have learn the embedding

Environment
Platform: Linux-4.15.0-55-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
spaCy version: 2.1.6
Python version: 3.5.2